# Trouble incorporating jQuery UI dialog in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm somewhat new to Rails development and can't seem to incorporate jQuery UI into a Rails 5 app.

I installed the jquery-ui-rails gem from RubyGems and followed the documentation. I've referenced the dialog widget examples on the jQuery UI site(http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#entry-examples).

I've tried using that code as-is, as well as putting the JavaScript in the javascript directory in the Rails assets folder. I've tried writing a code a couple ways, but no matter what, the button tag and dialog div tag both display on the page with no click, nor does the click work. I'm sure it's my syntax, but I need a nudge in the right direction. I know JavaScript, just apparently not with Rails.

application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
  $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  });

});
```

I've also tried it like this in the same file:

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

index.html.erb:

```
<button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm a dialog</div>
```

I just want the "open the dialog" button to display on its own, and open a dialog box when clicked instead of the dialog tag content just being embedded in the page. I don't know why I can't figure this out. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The code looks ok (just like the documentation), how did you integrate jquery-ui? show your gemfile, application.js and application.css, maybe you have something wrong there

Comment: jquery is not bundled in Rails 5 anymore so it's likely the reason. Anw, show Gemfile, application.js then someone can help you.

Comment: Awesome. It works now. I did include the jQuery-UI gem, but not the jQuery gem. For some reason, I took it for granted that jQuery just shipped with Rails and since bundle didn't flag me about a dependency I didn't even think about it.